# Intercept any ajax call on the page and detect what element triggered it

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm following other question on StackOverlow regarding tracking AJAX calls **without jQuery's methods `$.ajaxStart`** (and other similar methods from `$.ajax...` group).

The only issue is that those jQuery methods have properties like `event.target.activeElement` which points to the element that triggered the AJAX call (eg. dropdown element).

I'm trying to achieve the same effect without using jQuery. Intercepting requests was mentioned many times in other questions here, but none of them asked the question how to extract triggering element. For instance I'm using this piece of code:

```
(function() {
var origOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
    console.log('request started!');
    this.addEventListener('load', function() {
        console.log('request completed!');

    });
    origOpen.apply(this, arguments);
};
})();
```

How to figure out which element caused AJAX call in code like that?

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you want to get "activeElement" using JS, you should use "document.activeElement".

It contains current focused element.

Ajax calls could be called by click or code processing, so if you want, you need to manually handle what triggered it.

Is it helpful for you?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Already tested `document.activeElement` and it's not pointing to the right element in this case. Perhaps the activeElement is being changed somehow in the chain of callbacks and different stages of ajax call, but anyway for `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open` it's not poiting to any element but into entire page. When tested when `ajaxStart` it points to the proper element. 
I can skip code processing case. I'm interested only in click's and other user interactions.

Comment: JQuery AJAX has a own factory to make xhr requests, so they can pass contextElement to the method. Normally, XHR doesn't know where event was originally emitted. But you can create own object for XHR and then use it for all your requests. Look at the https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js.